# Do I have to manually attach a gtk signal handler when I specified the function name in glade?

Tags: gtk, glade, gtkmm

I'm writing my first gtk program, using gtkmm, and glade.
I made a filechooserbutton and it has a signal called file-set
So I set that to what I assume is the function name I want it to call when the file is chosen.
But then I see here:
http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-builder-accessing-widgets.html.en

That they're manually getting the dialog widget and setting a button signal handler in the code.
Which is the right way to do it?

And while I'm here any links to good examples would be handy, they seem to be few and far between. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
// create the UI
refUI = Gtk::Builder::create();
refUI->add_from_file(grq::GLADE_FILE);

// grab your widget
refUI->get_widget("but_new", but_new); // Gtk::ToolButton *but_new;
but_new->signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MainWindow::on_new_game));

// your signal handler looks something like this :)
void MainWindow::on_new_game() {}
```

**edit:**

Basically the *this is the object on which you will be calling the function your signal handler.

This is what my main looks like:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    Gtk::Main       kit(argc, argv);
    MainWindow      main_window;

    kit.run(*main_window.window);

    return 0;
}
```

`MainWindow` is basically a class that wraps GtkWindow and defines the widgets, a. la.:

```
class MainWindow
{

private:
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> refUI;

//
// Widgets
//

Gtk::ToolButton *but_about;

public:

// The window. This is public so we can hook into events and
// call kit.run(window) against it, if needed.
Gtk::Window *window;


MainWindow()
{
    // Load the data for this window and it's widgets.
    refUI = Gtk::Builder::create();
    refUI->add_from_file(grq::GLADE_FILE);


    // The window
    refUI->get_widget("main_window", window);


    // Widgets              
    refUI->get_widget("but_about", but_about);
    but_about->signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MainWindow::on_about));

            ...

}


virtual ~MainWindow()
{
    if (window != NULL)
    {
        delete window; // Frees all the children for the window, too.
    }
}

    virtual void on_about()
    {
            // stuff
    }

};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-signals-overview.html.en although knowing which signal to connect to is also not trivial :S

Comment: Right, I've seen that in a ton of places... what I'm not getting is the *this part.

Comment: What  is 'this' in this context?

Comment: Okay, I see what you're doing. So it's logically a global function that you tied to a class. I guess that's just how it's going to get done. It just feels not very clean c++ to me. But it's gotta be how it's gotta be. Thanks.

Comment: Upon more reflection, this isn't so bad. It ties things together in objects, I haven't gotten it working yet, but I will. I'm trying to avoid thinking about what must be going on in mem_fun.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question as an afterthought in another stackoverflow question.

But I don't remember which one it was.

The answer seems to be that you have to programmatically add the signal handler to the widget in your code, the gtkbuilder won't do it for you.